# Multiple line quote in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I am looking for the equivalent of the multiple line code feature in Markdown for quotes. For code blocks I can conveniently write:

````
```
    this is a code example
```
````

Does anyone know if something like the following is possible?

```
>>>
    this should be rendered as a multiple line quote
>>>
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use this notation also for multiple lines:

```
> **Stack1**: https://stackoverflow.com/  
this is split on 2 lines but renders on 1  
> **Stack2**: https://stackoverflow.com/ 
> **Stack3**: https://stackoverflow.com/
```

> **Stack1**: https://stackoverflow.com/
>   this is split on 2 lines but renders on 1
>   **Stack2**: https://stackoverflow.com/
>   **Stack3**: https://stackoverflow.com/

For line breaks you could either use `</br>` or `double space` at the end of line

Comment: Why use the nesting? Most markdown renderers will run multiple block quotes together if they’re sequential.

Comment: If you want one element per line this is a way to achieve it. Otherwise it would just concatenate all together in one line.

Comment: If you put an extra line break between them they'll show up on separate lines. That is identical to your solution, but doesn't require the extra column of `>` characters, and doesn't render the extra line. You might like the look of the double line, and that's fine, but it's the line break between them that's doing the work here, not the extraneous `>` characters.

Comment: you are completely right. I just tested it works as you say, so I revert my answer:
> something </br>
> something else

Comment: DOUBLE SPACE - Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I don't know any markdown implementation that has such a feature. However, most of them support [lazy block quotes](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.12/#block-quotes), so that you have to write the `>` only once per paragraph:

```
> This is a blockquote on two
lines.
```

Comment: If you want one per line I think you nel th8s

Answer (score 8):

You can use `<blockquote>` tags for multi-line quotes.

```
<blockquote>
This is one paragraph.

This is another paragraph.
</blockquote>
```

It will appear as:

> This is one paragraph.
>
> This is another paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

In Slack,

```
<<<
line one
line two
```

seems to work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is about markdown, not slack.